# how to aggregate mongodb collection data in laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have collection like this

```
 {
    "wl_total" : 380,
    "player_id" : 1241,
    "username" : "Robin",
    "hand_id" : 292656,
    "time" : 1429871584
}
{
    "wl_total" : -400,
    "player_id" : 1243,
    "username" : "a",
    "hand_id" : 292656,
    "time" : 1429871584
}
```

as both collection  have same hand_id i want to aggregate both these collection on the basis of hand_id 
i want result as combine of

```
data=array(
       'hand_id'=>292656,
        'wl_total'=>
                   {
                    0=>380,
                    1=>-400
                   },
         'username'=>
                   {
                    0=>"Robin",
                    1=>"a"
                   },
          "time"=>1429871584
     )
```

Comment: That's not an array. It's json.

Comment: yeah but i want to get data from db as i mention in json format

Comment: So the output of your db is at the top of your question?

Comment: no the second one at the bottom 'data' i have shown you as an array for readability but actually output will in json

Comment: Ah. I see. So at the top of your question is your expected output.

Comment: no the top is in json which is my collection in data base the output i want is at bottom it will also be in json i shown here in json just for readability

Answer (score 2):

You basically want a [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by the "hand_id" common to all players, and then [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) to different arrays in the document and then also do something with "time", I took `$max`. Nees to be an [accumulator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/) of some sort at any rate.

Also not sure what your underlying collection name is, but you can call this in laravel with a construct like this:

```
$result = DB::collection('collection_name')->raw(function($collection)
{
    return $collection->aggregate(array(
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => '$hand_id',
                'wl_total' => array(
                    '$push' => '$wl_total'
                ),
                'username' => array(
                    '$push' => '$username'
                ),
                'time' => array( 
                    '$max' => '$time'
                )
            )
        )   
    ));
});
```

Which returns output ( shown in json ) like this:

```
{
        "_id" : 292656,
        "wl_total" : [
                380,
                -400
        ],
        "username" : [
                "Robin",
                "a"
        ],
        "time" : 1429871584
}
```

Personally I would have gone for a single array with all the infomation in it for the grouped "hand", but I supose you have your reasons why you want it this way.

Comment: i want to show data in pagination if wl_total is positive then it will be a winner if negative then will be a looser and if it will be in single array how i will differentiate who will be winner or which username will be a winner or which will be a looser ... if you have any suggestion please recommend me thanks :)

Comment: and also when i run this query it showing data but not for all like wl_total , username,time but if i run this query with one of these it is showing correct data

Comment: @user2377300 Your fairly new here, so the concept of a "question" is that you only get to ask one only. If you have another question then you need to post that as a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You only get the answer to the question you asked and it is clearer that way. This is not a mailing list or forum but a repository of "questions" and "answers" to also be referenced by others. Ask a new question for additional information specific to your new task.

Comment: @user2377300 Not if your data looks like how you presented it. It is grouping common to "hand_id" and that means all documents that have the same "hand_id" will value the respective fields pushed into the marked arrays.